# Are there complex solutions for $z^3=\bar z$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm asked to solve $z^3=\bar z$. I got $z=0, 1, -1$. Are there any complex solutions $a+bi$  to this though?

Comment: Yes, like $i$. Use polar coordinates to find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a+bi)^3 = (a^3 - 3ab^2) + (3a^2b - b^3)i = a - bi$

$a^3 - 3ab^2 = a, 3a^2b - b^3 = -b$

If $a = 0$, then $-b^3 = -b$, and the only reals which statisfy that is $b = 0, 1, -1$

If $b = 0$, then similarly $a^3 = a$ so $a = 0, 1, -1$

So far this gives $0, -1, 1, i, -i$

If $a, b \neq 0$,

$a^2 - 3b^2 - 1 = 0, b^2 - 3a^2 - 1 = 0$. This implies $a = b$, so $a^2 - 3a^2 - 1 = 0 \rightarrow 2a^2 = -1$ which is impossible in the reals.

Answer (score 8):

Writing $z = re^{it}$, we have that

$$r^3 e^{3it} = re^{-it}$$

Taking absolute values, we find that $r^3 = r$, so that $r = 0$ or $r = \pm 1$. In the second two cases, we get that

$$e^{3it} = e^{-it} \implies e^{4it} = 1$$

It follows that $4t$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi$, so there are corresponding complex solutions.

Comment: Usually one sets $r\ge0$, when writing $z=re^{it}$. Not that it makes much difference.

Comment: This answer is helpful in understanding the apparent contradiction of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra between the existence of _five_ solutions with the seeming "cubic" polynomial $ \ z^3 \ - \ \overline{z} \ = \ 0 \ $ .  There are really two moduli to be considered, one of which ( $ r = 0 $ ) may only provide one solution, and the other ( $ r = 1 $ ) provides, in fact, four solutions.

Answer (score 2):

What about $i$?  $~~~i^3=-i=\overline{i}$ and also $-i$

Comment: I don't know why I couldn't think of that :-/

Comment: are those all of them?

Comment: Well, $-i$ should work too.

Comment: i put in $-i$ as well